# Sending HTTP request using Guzzle

Tags: php, json, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to send a post request using Guzzle 6 http client. I am sending two requests one with content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (`form_params` in Guzzle) and the other as `application/json` (`json` in Guzzle).

I initialise the client as below (`forms_params` and `json` respectively):

```
$data1 = array("c1" => "a", "c2" => null)
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post(
  "http://localhost/callback",
  array(
    "form_params" => $data1,          // send as x-www-form-urlencoded
  )
);


$data2 = array("c1" => "a", "c2" => null)
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post(
  "http://localhost/callback",
  array(
    "json" => $data2,                 // send as json
  )
);
```

The response that I receive does have not identical data/body:

Output for `form_params` : `Data -> {"c1":"a"}`

Output for `json` : `Data -> {"c1":"a","c2":null}`

I am not understanding why it does not send identical data for above requests. Could this be a bug in Guzzle? Is there any way to solve this (apart from removing nulls before sending request)?

**UPDATE** : As requested endpoint code (both requests are read using same code)

```
if ($$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] == "application/json") {
    $jsonstr = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $formData = json_decode($jsonstr, true);
} else {
    $formData = $_POST;
}
echo "Data -> " . json_encode($formData);
```

**UPDATE 2** : I went through the links provided in comments about this being expected behaviour in Guzzle.

But why I asked this question in first place is because I faced an issue of signature mismatch.

When I send the request, I add a header with a signature which is nothing but `hash_hmac("sha256", json_encode($data), "secret_key")`. So I get different signatures when sending data as `json` and `form_params` (since the data received is different in case of `form_params` as null values are discarded/not sent). First, I thought it might be because of a bug in Guzzle but it isn't.

Is there anyway to solve this signature issue?

Comment: Why would it be a bug in Guzzle if you endpoint is returning different data? Show your endpoint code so we can get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @JonStirling Updated question with endpoint code

Comment: Aha, this isn't strictly a bug. Guzzle appears to use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#109466) which seems to filter out stuff with empty values. I.e. in the first request, c2 isn't actually getting sent.

Comment: Its covered here: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/973 and especially here: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1181 not a bug notice the last comment.

Comment: @JonStirling Are u sure that's the case, I only found one occurrance in Guzzle code  (class - `UriTemplate` - method `expandMatch`) which calls that function. I put a breakpoint there and it didn't reach it. Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: According to https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1783 it does. If you search the repo, you also see if in the Client class https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/a1c4a74bf31d4e41d783fafb635c806cc19c2e9b/src/Client.php#L303

Comment: @JonStirling yes were right, it does call that and I missed that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks will look into those issues.

Comment: @JonStirling Please see my Update 2 and I appreciate if you can point in right direction with that.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Stirling and Lawrence Cherone noticed already, [it's not a bug according to Guzzle's authors](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1181#issuecomment-125448381).

So the solution for you is to cast values to a string for `form_params`. It makes sense, because URL encoded format (unlike JSON) doesn't have types (all is a string). And you everyone defines own conversion rules. In PHP (using `http_build_query`) it works like this, skipping `null`s at all.

Comment: Please see my Update 2